# Regular Expression for matching a numeric sequence?

Tags: regex

Does anyone know of a regular expression for matching on a sequence of four digits?  I need a match on ascending (1234), descending (4321), or the same (1111).  This would be strictly ascending/descending; 1357 shouldn't match.

Comment: Regex is not the best method to solve this problem.

Comment: Does `1357` count as an ascending match? What about `1289`? Is `0` before `1` or after `9`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here it is:

```
^(0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|3210|4321|5432|6543|7654|8765|9876|0000|1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|6666|7777|8888|9999)$
```

Comment: lol.  I guess I was making it more complicated than I needed to.

Comment: It can be more complicated, but less verbose.  See my solution below

Answer (score 38):

To match a 4-digit number consisting of the same digit:

```
^([0-9])\1{3}$
```

Or if you prefer assertion capture:

```
^(?=([0-9]))\1{4}$
```

For the rest, it may be easier to not use regex.

If ascending digits sequence must be contiguous, then simply see if it's a 4-length substring of `"0123456789"`. Reverse the string for descending.

For non-contiguous strictly ascending sequence (e.g. `1289` a match, `1337` not a match), you can use this regex:

```
^(?=\d{4}$)0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?
```

The assertion ensures that there are 4 digits. The rest should be obvious.

---

#### Java example

Here it is in Java, matching 4 digits, either strictly repeating, strictly increasing, or strictly decreasing.

```
    String[] tests = {
        "123", "12345", "3333", "1357", "1537", "7531", "2371", "1337", "0001"
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.printf("%s = %b%n", test, test.matches(
            "^(?=\\d{4}$)(?:(.)\\1*|0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?|9?8?7?6?5?4?3?2?1?0?)$"
        ));
    }
```

Output:

```
123 = false
12345 = false
3333 = true
1357 = true
1537 = false
7531 = true
2371 = false
1337 = false
0001 = false
```

The regex again is:

```
^          : (starting from beginning)
(?=\d{4}$) : (assert there are 4 digits to end)
(?:        : (must then match any of these three in a non-capturing group)
   (.)\1*                : all same digit
|  0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?  : strictly increasing
|  9?8?7?6?5?4?3?2?1?0?  : strictly decreasing
)$ : (to end)
```

Comment: That is some nice work.  Thank you for breaking down the expression with comments.

Comment: How can we use the similar logic for the Alphabets such as I want to check in a string is there strictly increasing/decreasing alphabets? For example ABCD, GHIJ, mnop, pomn etc

Comment: Your answer should work for me but don't know why it's not returning anything when applied on 111110123456333399876.

Answer (score 13):

```
public static boolean isDigitAscendingSequence(String ssn) {
    return "0123456789".contains(ssn);
}
```

The same logic with descending sequences

Comment: And maybe adding the zero on the end as well as the beginning.