# Finding (regex?) 10 digits in a row (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I am facing a problem i am not capable to solve. I have a string consisting of not needed text and 10 digit numbers who always start with "2" or "6". I need to get those in 10digit numbers into an array. I thought of regex and found this article [Regular Expression for matching a numeric sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884384/regular-expression-for-matching-a-numeric-sequence) which is pretty close to what i need (except the descending/ascending thing) yet, as i could never and will NEVER be able to understand regex, i cant modify to my needs. If anyone could help me out here i would highly appreciate it!

Here is a sample of my string:

```
".........693 7098469 - ZQH X Bop. Hrtepou 50 flerpoUrroXn ........210 5014166 - 0E000PA E KapaoAn Anpn-rPou 21
EAArivtg .....................................................210 9618677 - MAPIA KapaoAri Arpn-rptou 21 Elanvolo .. 210 9643623 - MAPIA E ...................................................... 210 9643887 - MAPIA 0 loucrrivou 8 HX.toOrran ..............210 9914534 AIPITAKHE APTEMIOE n Avrtnopou 22
Reptcrrept ....._.........._......._................697 7440896 , -10AN."
```

Thank you very much in advance!
Greetings from Greece!

Comment: Thanks for the edit... i couldnt get the damn code block in there! :-)

Comment: Okay.. what have you tried?  Show us what you've attempted and why it didn't work.

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava, All the numbers like `693 7098469` , `210 5014166` , etc.. the numbers that start with `2` or `6`.

Comment: So far, the only thing i was able to try out with regex was this ^(?=([0-9]))\1{10}$ and to be honest i dont know what exactly i was trying out! i really cannot understand regex....

Comment: Maybe you should learn about it then ;). If we just provide you with a regex, you won't learn anything from it.

Comment: For a start, you might look at [this](http://regex101.com/r/sS2rB3) (especially the explanation). The explanation should be clear enough to understand.

Comment: You CAN do this reg exp. It's almost simpler than logging into your OS... "I can't do regex" sounds like an excuse to have others do your work.

Comment: @Jerry Very good link! thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see your string your digits have an space between, and if you want strictly make your selections this is the regex:

```
[62]\d{2}\s*\d{7}
```

***Explanation***:

```
[62]    # Start with 6 or 2
\d{2}   # 2 more digits
\s*     # any number of white spaces
\d{7}   # 7 more digits
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/jA5qE7)

and PHP code which has `preg_match_all` to match all occurrences of those strings:

```
preg_match_all("/[62]\d{2}\s*\d{7}/", $text, $matches);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 693 7098469
    [1] => 210 5014166
    [2] => 210 9618677
    [3] => 210 9643623
    [4] => 210 9643887
    [5] => 210 9914534
    [6] => 697 7440896
)
```

[PHP live demo](http://3v4l.org/0Jo1U)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I really think regex will be my nemesis for ever....

Comment: @JimBadanis-Kapirnas *Beside its regular name - Regular Expressions - it's so nasty!*

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

```
<?php
$x=
".........693 7098469 - ZQH X Bop. Hrtepou 50 flerpoUrroXn ........210 5014166 - 0E000PA E KapaoAn Anpn-rPou 21     EAArivtg  ....................................................210 9618677 - MAPIA KapaoAri Arpn-rptou 21 Elanvolo .. 210 9643623 - MAPIA E ...................................................... 210 9643887 - MAPIA 0 loucrrivou 8 HX.toOrran ..............210 9914534 AIPITAKHE APTEMIOE n Avrtnopou 22
Reptcrrept ....._.........._......._................697 7440896 , -10AN.";
$x=str_replace(' ','',$x);
preg_match_all('/((2|6)\d{9})/',$x,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

And the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6937098469
    [1] => 2105014166
    [2] => 2109618677
    [3] => 2109643623
    [4] => 2109643887
    [5] => 2109914534
    [6] => 6977440896
)
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a pretty cool page, that visualize the regex code for better understading:
https://www.debuggex.com/

this should work

((?:2|6)[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7})

[image: Regular expression visualization]