# regex to check all digits in are same or not

Tags: javascript, regex

I have input field which takes 12 digits number. I want to throw error when user enters 12 digits same number. Atleast one number has to be different.

E.g

```
   111111111111 - Error

   111111111112 - Ok

   123456789012 - Ok
```

I tried this (but i want inverse of the specified regex )

```
var pattern = "^([0-9])\\1{3}$";
var str = "5555";
pattern = new RegExp(pattern);
if(!pattern.test(str))
{
    alert('Error');
}
else
{
    alert('Valid');
}
```

code from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2884414/1169180

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wn9scv3m/10/

**Edit:** No manipulation in     `if(!pattern.test(str))` in this line is allowed

Comment: So why not reverse the test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{11}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nS3fB8/1)

---

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Match line start
- `(\d)` - match first digit and capture it in back reference #1 i.e. `\1`
- `(?!..)` is a negative lookahead
- `(?!\1+$)` means disallow the match if first digit is followed by same digit (captured group) till end.
- `\d{11}$` match next 11 digit followed by line end

Comment: `111111111111` should produce error ! i tried this in fiddle

Comment: @Shaggy The regex is correct, I'm pretty sure you didn't escape the `\\` when you tried: see the [updated exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/wn9scv3m/12/)

Comment: Yes I did and have posted a demo also to show how this regex works.

Comment: a little off topic, even if I upvoted I think it could be great to say a word on how it works (specially the negative lookahead) in your answer, regex101 explanation is not always crystal clear :)

Comment: Fair enough @Tensibai, I added some explanation in my answer.