# RegEx for pin number

Tags: java, regex

Im looking to create a `RegEx` for `java` to validate a Pin Number that needs to be at least exactly 6 character long and not all numbers can be equal.

I got `/\d{6}/` but I I'm having a little trouble finding out how to make sure all 6 numbers should be different, so `000000` is invalid, while `000001` should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex with a negative lookahead assertion:

```
^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{5}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3b8L6m/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(\d)`: Match and capture first digit in group #1
- `(?!\1+$)`: Negative lookahead to assert we don't have repetitions of same digit till end
- `\d{5}`: Match remaining 5 digits
- `$`: End

Comment: Basically, [you have already answered such a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27063848/3832970).

Comment: Good find, that is pretty close. There was no way I could recall that answer myself :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @anubhava and I hope the douchebag that voted my question down burns alive. I really needed the answer pretty fast and as RegEx features changes from one language to another, I couldn't find anything specific to Java. Also, glad to know I'll get to keep this around for JS :)