# How to validate a contiguous sequence of digits with regex?

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex for PIN validation.

The PIN is 4-digits and must not consist of contiguous numbers.

Examples of contiguous numbers:

`[ 1111, 1234, 9876, 8888, 0987, 0123 ]`

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435883/regex-for-pin-number) link, but it only checks for identical digits, not contiguous ones.

Could you suggest working regex  for me?

Comment: This feels like a homework problem.  Why would you want such a check in the real world?

Comment: @JeffBennett Thanks for reply,
but bro this is not a homework problem if it is a homework then i can find solution for that like :- (^(?=^(?:(?!0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|7890|0987|9876|8765|7654|6543|5432|4321|3210).)*$)(?=^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{3}$).*$ ) this regex, but i don't want static type of regex.

Comment: Try something like `:-  (\d{1,},){1,}\d{1,}` - if for digits only - every block except the last one has comma.

Comment: There's simply no way to do what you want to do using `RegExp` only, short of the unwieldy giant string you mentioned, because it involves math.

Comment: I would suggest cutting the PIN in pieces and compare them.

Comment: What exactly is a “continuous number”? It seems to be a number that next to or the same as the previous, with 0 considered to be next to 9. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

**The regex only match**

That is why a regex like (adjusted to 4 digits):

```
^(\\d)(?!\\1+$)\\d{3}$
```

, showed in link "this" (link found question) will only check for identical digits.

**Note: The original expression is made a bit smaller, so it will be easier to follow - without the quantifiers. In expression '(?<!\1)\d', "\1 -> group(1)" matches “\d -> a didgit” that is not preceded by “group(1)”, using negative lookbehind. It doesn’t match an equal digit.**

We would like to have arithmetic operators directly in the regex, applying it on "group(1)", in order to solve it with only regex, but that is not supported by regex.

**Here is an alternative, not regex though, first the core code snippet:**

```
int digit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pin.charAt(i)));
int nextDigit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pin.charAt(i + 1)));
if (digit >= nextDigit - 1 && digit <= nextDigit + 1) {
    resultMap.put(pin, false);
    break;
}
```

**Code snippet in context and "testbench":**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> inputs =
            Arrays.asList("1111", "1234", "9876"
                    , "8888", "0987", "0123"
                    , "1358", "0268", "9635");

    Map<String, Boolean> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String pin : inputs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pin.length() - 1; i++) {
            resultMap.put(pin, true);
            int digit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pin.charAt(i)));
            int nextDigit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pin.charAt(i + 1)));
            if (digit >= nextDigit - 1 && digit <= nextDigit + 1) {
                resultMap.put(pin, false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(resultMap);
}
```

**Output:**

```
{1111=false, 1234=false, 9876=false, 8888=false, 0987=false, 0123=false, 1358=true, 0268=true, 9635=true}
```