# How to write a regular expression for a number of maximum length l where all the digits should not be same?

Tags: regex

I've used `^\d{3,20}$`  to limit the maximum length to 20 and to use only digits but how do I specify that all the digits in the input should not be same like 99999999

Comment: Why is 99999999 invalid? Is 99999998 invalid? Please edit the question to clarify

Comment: @bobblebubble See [regex to check all digits in are same or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063822/regex-to-check-all-digits-in-are-same-or-not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead to fail the match if all digits are same:

```sh
^(?!(\d)\1+$)\d{3,20}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AQcNdu/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?!`: Start negative lookahead

  - `(\d)`: Match first digit and capture in group #1
  - `\1+$`: Match 1+ occurrences of same value we have in group #1
- `)`: End negative lookahead